# Translating routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to do a simple language translation for my routes but I really can't understand why my approach isn't working. I would like to get `www.example.com/it/camere` by calling `rooms_path(locale: :it)` and `www.example.com/en/rooms` by calling `rooms_path(locale: :en)`.
For example, look at the following routes:

```
get ":locale/rooms" => "home#rooms", constraints: { locale: "en" }, as: "rooms"
get ":locale/camere" => "home#rooms", as: "rooms"
```

I get the following results:

```
app.rooms_path               # => error         OK
app.rooms_path(locale: "it") # => 'it/camere'   OK
app.rooms_path(locale: "en") # => 'en/camere'   Why?!?
```

And with the following routes (notice the second constraint):

```
get ":locale/rooms" => "home#rooms", constraints: { locale: "en" }, as: "rooms"
get ":locale/camere" => "home#rooms", constraints: { locale: "it" }, as: "rooms"
```

I get the following results:

```
app.rooms_path               # => error         OK
app.rooms_path(locale: "it") # => 'it/camere'   OK
app.rooms_path(locale: "en") # => error         Lol?!? This is weird!
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?
I have already read about 3 times the Rails article about routing but It didn't help.

P.S. I would prefer **not to use plugins** in order to learn :)

**EDIT:**

This is my what I get by calling rake routes:

```
rooms GET    /:locale/rooms(.:format)    home#rooms {:locale=>"en"}
rooms GET    /:locale/camere(.:format)   home#rooms {:locale=>"it"}
root         /(:locale)(.:format)        home#index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first case

You can't use `:as` twice with the same name. The second time of using it replaces the previous `xxx_path` definition and you'll end up with the `rooms_path` which points to `:locale/camere` with no constraints. Looks like you've overestimated the Rails' magic.

About the second case

```
get ":locale/camere" => "home#rooms", constraints: { locale: "it" }, as: "rooms"
```

fails on calling `app.rooms_path(locale: "en")` because there's only one `rooms_path` is available and it expects `:locale` to be `"it"`. Calling it with `"en"` naturally leads to an unresolved route complain.

**Take a look at [define_url_helper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L193) if you want to see the source of it.**

Comment: Gosh, I was suspecting this. I thought that I would be able to call the same url helper with different constraints. Any other way to achieve my result without a plugin? I could use two different helpers but then I would loose the benefit of just calling `rooms_path(...)` in my views. Am I right? Thanks.